# Precise Definition: from book "how to think about analysis" by Lara Alcock

Tags: real-analysis

I'm currently struggling with distinguishing between the two separate definitions presented in the book:

1. A function $f: X \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is bounded above on $X$ if and only if there exist $M \in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. for all $x$ there exists $x\in X$, $f(x) \leq M$.
2. $M$ is an upper bound for the function $f$ on the set $X$ if and only if there exists $x \in X$, $f(x) \leq M$.

According to the book, there is a subtle difference because (1) is about the function and (2) is about the number.

However, they both seem identical to me.

Comment: 1 is a definition of *bounded above* which, as you say is about $f$. 2 is a definition of *upper bound* which is both about the function $f$ and the number $M$.

Comment: They are different and second one is wrong. It is presented only as an example to see the difference between these two statement. The last statement can be corrected by changing "there exists $x$" with "for all $x$". There is another difference between the statements. First one defines "bounded above" and second one talks about "upper bound"  of something that is "bounded above". This is like defining  a "rich person" and "income"  of a "rich person" .

Answer (score 1):

I suspect for the second definition you mean to write "...if and only if **for all** $x\in X$..."

The first one says what it means for a function to be bounded above. The second one says what it means for a number to be an upper bound for a function.

For example, consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\sin(x)$. This function is bounded above because $f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Any number $M\geq 1$ is an upper abound for $f$, by the same reasoning.

They are related. A function is bounded above if and only if there exists an upper bound for the function.

Answer (score 0):

1. A real-valued **function** $f$ has the property “bounded above” if there exists a number such that $f(x)$ is always less than that number.
2. A real **number** $M$ has the property of being “an upper bound for a function $f$” if and only if the function value is always less than the number.

The properties are talking about exactly the same subject, in that a function $f$ is bounded above by $M$, just when $M$ is an upper bound for the function $f$.

The *focus* of the definitions is the only difference: the first is a property “being bounded above” that *functions* can have, and the second one is a property “being an upper bound” that *numbers* can have.